# How can I ref the current state of an element with forwardRef in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I'm trying to create a .png image from a charts.js chart.

Here is the code snippet in question:

```
const DSampleChart = () => {
  let ref = useRef(null);

  const downloadImage = useCallback(() => {
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = "chart.png";
    link.href = ref.current.toBase64Image();
    link.click();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <button type="button" onClick={downloadImage}>
        Download
      </button>
      <div>
        <WbrChart ref={ref} data={chartonedata} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

It's complaining about the `toBase645Image()` but I think that's because the `ref.current` is empty. And the ref is empty because it's referenced in a function and apparently, you can't use `ref` in a function?

> Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

But I'm not familiar with `forwardRef` and ended up messing it up more the more I touched it.

[Here is a sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-taussig-kgv5lv) for you to play with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in JSX, only the official tags can accept `ref` prop by default. the components must be created by `forwardRef` function to be able to accept `ref` prop.

here is what you should do with `WbrChart` to make it work:

```
import React, { forwardRef } from "react";

const WbrChart = forwardRef(({ data }, ref) => {
  return <Line ref={ref} options={options} data={data} />;
});

WbrChart.displayName = "WbrChart" // you must set a `displayName` for debugging cases manually, because `forwardRef` is not smart enough to get it from the component name
```

now, you can pass `ref` prop as you already did:

```
<WbrChart ref={ref} data={chartonedata} />
```

you can also check and test it from my cloned code sand box here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-tdd-wnqnd5?file=/src/App.js